# curl get error time out

Tags: php

```
<?php
 date_default_timezone_set('asia/ho_chi_minh');
 require_once "include/my_Connect.php";
 require_once "include/my_Function.php";
 set_time_limit(0);
 $merchant = "lazada.vn";
 $update_time = "25-09-2017";
 $time = time();
 $curl = curl_init();
  curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
   CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.accesstrade.vn/v1/datafeeds?domain=" .$merchant ."&limit=200",
   CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
   CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
   CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
   CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
   CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
   CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
   CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
     "authorization: Token 1CBmSpWYukcKGGttew8ZYiyKFw4GHKD5",
     "cache-control: no-cache",
     "content-type: application/json",
   ),
 ));
    .... Please view full code 
    ?>
```

My Full Code here

> http://notepad.vn/zgembji94

I'm newbie, my code maybe too nob but i still want to learn more to code a website compare price.

I hope someone can help me fix it so that I can learn.

Comment: Welcome to `StackOverflow`, please take some time to read "[How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure about timeouts of PHP and Curl. To debug and resolve the issue, you need to do following:

To tell Curl to never timeout when a transfer is still active, you need to set CURLOPT_TIMEOUT to 0, instead of 30.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 0);
```

In PHP, again, you must remove time limits or PHP itself (after 30 seconds by default) will kill the script along Curl's request. This alone should fix your issue.

```
set_time_limit(0);
// The maximum execution time, in seconds. If set to zero, no time limit is imposed.
```

Both these things help to sort out the issue, otherwise there is issue in your Curl URL that might not respond at all.

Comment: I use all option but always get old errror, i think my script have problem. So can you check my script ?

Comment: First check your URL that is working fine or not: https://api.accesstrade.vn/v1/datafeeds?domain=" .$merchant ."&limit=200

Comment: Can you tell what is the exact static URL with the value of $merchant. We can try with some other Curl script if your URL works.